# Adding more than one status to project using php code for perfex crm

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question.. i am following this direction to add new a status to a project.
https://help.perfexcrm.com/add-new-project-status/

```
------------------------
<?php
hooks()->add_filter('before_get_project_statuses','my_add_custom_project_status');

function my_add_custom_project_status($current_statuses){
    // Push new status to the current statuses
    $current_statuses[] = array(
           'id'=>50, // new status with id 50
           'color'=>'#989898',
           'name'=>'Planning',
           'order'=>10,
           'filter_default'=>true, // true or false
        );
    // Return the statuses
    return $current_statuses;
}
---------------------------
```

but it only show one. What should I add to code to add more than just one. I tried to cut and paste from function to return $current_statuses; and then changing the different value  in the array to depict the additional status, but it keeps on returning error.

Any suggestion is appreciated..

Comment: make a dimensional array, as you till now have only one.

Comment: How do i do that? can you please give me an example from the code above? I am still learning php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define it so, but when you use the rsult you have to change the code that utilizes the array

```
$current_statuses = array(
                          array(
                                     'id'=>50, // new status with id 50
                                     'color'=>'#989898',
                                     'name'=>'Planning',
                                     'order'=>10,
                                     'filter_default'=>true, // true or false
                                  ),
                          array(
                                     'id'=>51, // new status with id 50
                                     'color'=>'#989898',
                                     'name'=>'Planning',
                                     'order'=>10,
                                     'filter_default'=>true, // true or false
                                  ),
                          array(
                                     'id'=>52, // new status with id 50
                                     'color'=>'#989898',
                                     'name'=>'Planning',
                                     'order'=>10,
                                     'filter_default'=>true, // true or false
                                  )
                      );
                      

echo $current_statuses[0][0];        // 50
echo $current_statuses[1]['id'];    //   51
```